# Creating the quantity update button for Cart System in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am creating the update button for the cart system in asp.net. What am I trying to do is to allow user key in the quantity items and then click the update button. Here is the design of the shopping cart system...

[image]

Unfortunately the update button doesn't work properly **after the first row**. I have debugged the problem and the for loop inside the **btn_update_Click** method returns the value of zero.

Is there any other way to overcome the problem? Thanks

Here is the source code:

```
<b><asp:Label ID="lbl_showResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></b>

                <asp:GridView ID="grv_cart" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sds_store" ShowHeader="True" GridLines="None" CssClass="table">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>                      
                            <ItemTemplate>                        
                                <a class="hyp_productimage imgLiquidFill imgLiquid productImage img-responsive" href='<%# string.Format("product.aspx?ProductID={0}", Eval("product_id")) %>'>
                                    <img src='<%#Eval("image") %>' />
                                </a> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Hyperlink ID="hyp_productname" Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("product.aspx?ProductID={0}", Eval("product_id")) %>'></asp:Hyperlink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_productQuantity" Text='<%# Eval("product_quantity") %>' CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="60" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>                                                                     
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_update" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CssClass="btn btn-warning" OnClick="btn_update_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_remove" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CssClass="btn btn-danger" onclick="btn_remove_Click"/>                                                                
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>                  

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Hyperlink ID="hyp_productcost" Text='<%#"$"+Eval("product_cost") %>' runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("product.aspx?ProductID={0}", Eval("product_id")) %>'></asp:Hyperlink>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>                           

                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_store" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:websiteConnection %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [product_id], [product_name], [product_cost], [product_description], [product_quantity], [image], [date] FROM [tbl_cart] WHERE [name] = @username AND [visible] = @visible">

                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:sessionparameter sessionfield="login" Name="username" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="visible" Type="string" DefaultValue="true" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <h4><asp:Label ID="lbl_totalCost" Text="" runat="server" CssClass="pull-right"></asp:Label></h4>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_buy" Text="Buy Now" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" OnClick="btn_buy_Click" />
```

Here's another source code for the .cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace websiteEcom
{
    public partial class cart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        // Open the connection for the sql
        private static SqlConnection conn;
        private static SqlCommand command;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create an instance for the connection of database
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["websiteConnection"].ToString();
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("", conn);

            // Checks how many items are there inside the cart database and display it to the label 
            CheckHowManyItem();

            // Multiply all the sums of the cost
            lbl_totalCost.Text = "Total Cost: $"+TotalProductCost().ToString();

        }

        // Checks how many items are there inside the cart database and display it to the label 
        public void CheckHowManyItem()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                // Retrieve the number of rows from the database
                string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_cart WHERE name = '{0}' AND visible = '{1}'", Session["login"], "true");
                command.CommandText = query;
                int numberOfItems = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                // If the number of rows is zero
                if (numberOfItems == 0)
                {
                    lbl_showResult.Text = "You have no items inside the cart.";
                    btn_buy.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If there is number of rows inside
                    lbl_showResult.Text = "There are currently " + numberOfItems + " inside the cart.";
                    btn_buy.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }


        protected void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the value from the button ASP.NET gridview
            Button btn = (Button)sender;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                // Make the cart invisible if the id matches with the grid view data source
                string query = string.Format("UPDATE tbl_cart SET visible = '{0}' WHERE id = '{1}'", "false", btn.CommandArgument);
                command.CommandText = query;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }


        // Multiply all the values of purchases together
        public int TotalProductCost()
        {
            int totalCost = 0;
            int currentCost = 0;
            int currentQuantity = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < grv_cart.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get the data values from the forms
                HyperLink hypCost = (HyperLink)grv_cart.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("hyp_productcost");
                TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)grv_cart.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("txt_productQuantity");

                // Sum the product quantity and the product cost               
                // Attempt to parse your value (removing any non-numeric values)
                currentQuantity = Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(txtQuantity.Text, @"[^\d]", ""));               

                // Attempt to parse your value (removing any non-numeric values)
                currentCost = Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(hypCost.Text, @"[^\d]", ""));

                currentCost *= currentQuantity;

                totalCost += currentCost;


            }
            return totalCost;

        }

        protected void btn_buy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the value from the button ASP.NET gridview
            Button btn = (Button)sender;

            foreach (GridViewRow grvCart in grv_cart.Rows)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(btn.CommandArgument);

                TextBox textQuantity = (TextBox)grvCart.FindControl("txt_productQuantity");
                int currentQuantity = Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(textQuantity.Text, @"[^\d]", ""));

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    // Update the cart quantity if the id matches with the grid view data source
                    string query = string.Format("UPDATE tbl_cart SET product_quantity = '{0}' WHERE id = '{1}'", currentQuantity, btn.CommandArgument);
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i think you don't need `foreach` loop in your update event, since you have button for each record,you can update same row as you doing in delete event

Answer (score 0):

Try using the RowCommand event (especially since you already have the CommandArgument set up).  That is the more appropriate way to handle this type of action (and that way you can just update one row at a time, without looping through all of them).

Handle the RowCommand event in your GridView declaration:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grv_cart" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sds_store" ShowHeader="True" 
    GridLines="None" CssClass="table" OnRowCommand="grv_cart_RowCommand">
```

And then your event handler would look like this:

```
protected void grv_cart_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow rowToUpdate = grv_cart.Rows[Int.Parse(e.CommandArgument)];
    TextBox textQuantity = (TextBox)rowToUpdate.FindControl("txt_productQuantity");
    int currentQuantity = Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(textQuantity.Text, @"[^\d]", ""));

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // Update the cart quantity if the id matches with the grid view data source
        string query = string.Format("UPDATE tbl_cart SET product_quantity = '{0}' WHERE id = '{1}'", currentQuantity, e.CommandArgument);
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("cart.aspx");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Note: You'll want to remove the OnClick handler from the update button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_update" Text="Update" runat="server" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' CssClass="btn btn-warning" />
```

Comment: Okay thanks. But the main problem is about the input. How does this method triggered?

Comment: @Minelava The method is triggered when a button (asp:Button, asp:LinkButton, etc) is clicked inside a Row of your GridView.